# Редактировать заголовок H1

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт http://green-yard-crimea.ru/ 
Заголовок которого "ГОСЕВОЙ ДОМ GREEN YARD" написан как на картинке №1 а необходимо сделать как на картинке №2 да плюс еще двух цветный. Как это можно осуществить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Внутрь заголовка `h1` вставить `span` или `strong` для которого задаете свой цвет текста:

```css
h1 {
  text-transform: inherit;
}

h1 span {
  color:#51ce73;
}
```

```html
<h1>Гостевой до "<span>Green Yard</span>"</h1>
```

Comment: Да это понятно с обычным кодом, а вот с Wordpress сложней. Если можно объясниете более детально.

Comment: @РусланПавлюк, что тут объяснять и какая разница обычный код или WP? Вставляете в админке текст где необходимо вместе `Гостевой до "<span>Green Yard</span>"` и обычно в нормальных темах все работает. А по поводу верстки чтобы такое элементарное понять нужно хоть чуточку почитать о верстке https://webref.ru/ ;)